# Does sqlite has something like case on procedural Level?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple, as it looks, question:

I am having Sqlite query where I am using temp tables and then joining those table, something like:

```
drop table if exists SourceA
create temp table SourceA (id int, value text);

insert into SourceA select id, value from TableA

drop table if exists SourceB
create temp table SourceB (id int, value text);

insert into SourceB select id, value from TableB 

select SourceA.*, SourceB.* from SourceA join SourceB on SourceA.id = SourceB.id
```

Now is it possible to create some sort of procedura if or case so for example one of those insert will not be executed, like:

```
bool merge = false;

drop table if exists SourceA
create temp table SourceA (id int, value text);

insert into SourceA select id, value from TableA

if(merge)
{
    drop table if exists SourceB
    create temp table SourceB (id int, value text);

    insert into SourceB select id, value from TableB 

    select SourceA.*, SourceB.* from SourceA join SourceB on SourceA.id = SourceB.id 
else
{
    select * from SourceA
}
```

Example of usage is simple, its like a condition when you determine seconds two dates, let's say second table counts missing seconds, so now if interval is too big app will crush. So i need to determine outside of SQL if such thing can be done, and pass it to SQL (basically it can be any condition that will exclude second insert from happening)

Comment: Is there any chance that the `merge` variable could be deduced by a query on a certain table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mange to handle my problem by using variables temp table like:

```
drop table if exists Variables;
create temp table Variables (MinDatetime Datetime, MaxDatetime Datetime);

insert into Variables Values(@MinDatetime, @MaxDatetime);
```

And then passing parameter from code, an just omitting result using case something like:

```
case when (Select MinDatetime from Variables) = 'None' or (Select MaxDatetime from Variables) = 'None' then 0
else value
end as value
```

And if value is 'None' it will return just plain 0

Answer (score -1):

SQLite is designed as an embedded database, to be used together with a 'real' programming language, so it does not have any procedural features.

Put the control logic into your actual program (or, if you don't have one, write a script).